# Codefights RecurringTask Issue

Tags: c++, date

I've been stuck for a couple hours in this problem and I cant figure it out. Could someone point me in the right direction?

## This is the question:

If you have a task that you need to complete on a regular basis, you can set it up in Asana as a recurring task. One option is to schedule the task to repeat every k weeks on specified days of the week.

It would be useful to be able to view the first n dates for which the task is scheduled. Given the first date for which the task is scheduled, return an array of the first n dates.

In this task, you'll likely need month lengths and weekday names, provided here:

Month lengths from January to December: 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31.

During leap years February has 29 days.
Names of weekdays: "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday".

January 1, 2015 was a Thursday.
Date is in format dd/mm/yyyy.

### Example

For firstDate = "01/01/2015", k = 2, daysOfTheWeek = ["Monday", "Thursday"] and n = 4, the output should be

```
recurringTask(firstDate, k, daysOfTheWeek, n) = 
    ["01/01/2015", "05/01/2015", "15/01/2015", "19/01/2015"]
```

Thanks for any help, here is my code (its a mess I think, im only 3 days into c++) just in case:

```
int dayofweek(int d, int m, int y){
    int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 };
    y -= m < 3;
    return ( y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
}

std::vector<std::string> recurringTask(std::string firstDate, int k, std::vector<std::string> daysOfTheWeek, int n) {
    std::vector<std::string> ans = {firstDate};
    bool is_leap = false;
    //date to ints for firstDate
    int d = std::stoi(firstDate.substr(0, 2));
    int m = std::stoi(firstDate.substr(3, 2));
    int y = std::stoi(firstDate.substr(6));

    //check if leap
    int add_days = 7 * k;
    if((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0){
        is_leap = true;
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < daysOfTheWeek.size(); j++){
            int max_d = 31;
            //month
            if(m == 2){
                if(is_leap){
                    max_d = 29;
                }else {
                    max_d = 28;
                }
            }else{
                max_d = 30;
            }
            
            if(d + add_days > max_d){
                //Go to next month
                d = d + add_days - max_d;
                m += 1;
                if(m > 12){
                    //Go to next year.
                    m = 1;
                    y += 1;
                }
                ans.push_back(std::to_string(d) + "/" + std::to_string(m) + "/" + std::to_string(y));
            }else{
                d += add_days;
                ans.push_back(std::to_string(d) + "/" + std::to_string(m) + "/" + std::to_string(y));
            }
            
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: When a problem is too difficult to solve in one pass, try to break it into smaller pieces. Solve one piece at a time and confirm each step is doing what you expect. If something doesn't work as expected, try to figure out why. I've been programming for 10 years and follow this process every day.

Comment: I just dont know how to get to each following day given the day name.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What have you tried? What's not working as expected?

Comment: Basically I have the "daysofTheWeek" variable which holds strings for each day that the task shall be scheduled (ie. "monday", "thursday") and a variable "k" which is what tells how many weeks apart the task should repeat. I dont know how to Use the "daysofTheWeek" variable to get the following dates that the program asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You on the right track.

First of all, your max_d logic is wrong. Max_d is dependent on the month.

```
vector<int> max_d{ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
```

query it against that vector. Also do the leap year check. The tricky part is given the daysOfTheWeek vector, you need to construct another vector holding all the days of the week in order with regards to your start date. What I mean by this is

first of all you are guaranteed to have a start date with the day of the week within the daysOfTheWeek vector

second if daysOfTheWeek = ["Monday", "Thursday"] and your start date is on a Thursday, you want to create a vector holding the corresponding days in numeric form.

```
vector<string> weekDays{ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
```

query it against that vector. So the logic is, I take the daysOfTheWeek vector and create a new vector holding the numeric form of the days..so this vector should contain [1, 4] for monday and thursday. Now I rearrange this vector so that the starting day comes first while keeping the order...so it becomes [4, 1]. Now I pop off the front so the vector just becomes [1] and for every task, I just need to print the start date and loop through this vector u just created and add each element to ur start date and print.

```
deque<int> dow;
    for (int i = 0; i < daysOfTheWeek.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < weekDays.size(); j++){
            if (daysOfTheWeek[i] == weekDays[j]){
                dow.push_back(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int startDow = dayofweek(stoi(day), stoi(month), stoi(year));
    while (dow.front() != startDow){
        dow.push_back(dow.front());
        dow.pop_front();
    }
    dow.pop_front();
```